# Bounded Distance function - triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space (where $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a distance function).

Define the bounded distance function $D : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ by:

$D(x,y) = d(x,y)\mathrm{,\ if\ } d(x,y)\leq1$

$D(x,y) = 1\mathrm{,\ if\ } d(x,y)>1$

I'm supposed to prove that $D$ is also a distance function on $X$ (so that $(X,D)$ is also a metric space).

I am doing okay, except when it comes to proving that $D$ satisfies the triangle identity. Can someone point me in the right direction?

MY ATTEMPT:

Let $x,y,z\in X$

CASE I: $d(x,z)\leq 1$

If $d(x,z)\leq 1$, then by definition of $D$, we have $D(x,z)=d(x,z)$. But $d$ is a distance function and so $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Since $D(x,z)=d(x,z)$, this implies $D(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

CASE II: $d(x,z)> 1$

If $d(x,z)>1$, then by definition of $D$, we have $D(x,z)=1$. This means that $D(x,z)<d(x,z)$. But $d$ is a distance function and so $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Since $D(x,z)<d(x,z)$, this implies $D(x,z) < d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

So I have proven that $D(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z\in X$.

Where do I proceed from here? I need to somehow show that the above implies that $D(x,z) \leq D(x,y)+D(y,z)$. I thought about breaking it up into further subcases, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Case distinction: at least one of the two terms on the right is $> 1$, or both are $\leqslant 1$.

Comment: So either: ($D(x,y)$>1), or ($D(y,z)$>1), or ($D(x,y)\leq 1$ and $D(y,z)\leq1$)?

Comment: You need a lower case $d$ there, $D(a,b) \leqslant 1$ is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that it is always true, that $D(x,z) \leq d(x,z)$, $D(x,z)\leq 1$ and that $d(x,z) \leq 1 \Rightarrow d(x,z)=D(x,y)$.

You need to look at two cases:

**Case 1:**

If $D(x,y)+D(y,z) <1$ then you know that both $D(x,y) <1$ and $D(y,z) <1$. Because $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality, we find that:

$D(x,z)\leq d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) = D(x,y)+D(y,z)$

**Case 2:**

If we have, however, that $D(x,y)+D(y,z) \geq1$ then it is obvious that:

$D(x,z)\leq1\leq D(x,y)+D(y,z)$

And so it's true for all $x,y,z \in X$

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your second case you have $d(x,z)>1$ so $D(x,z)=1.$ If the triangle inequality failed in the second case,then for some $x,y,z$ with $d(x,z)>1$ we would have $$(1)..... D(x.z)=1>D(x,y)+D(y,z)$$ which implies $$(2).....1>D(x,y) \text{ and } 1>D(y,z)$$ which in turn implies $$(3).....D(x,y)=d(x,y) \text{ and }D(y,z)=d(y,z).$$  Substituting (3) into (1) yields $$d(x,z)>1=D(x.z)>d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$a contradiction.